# ConversationHandler State did not pass in Python Telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am trying out the Python Telegram bot. I am trying to pass the state from a button to questionTwo. However, when I run it, it can successfully pass through /start and answerOne. Yet, it will stop at answerOne by displaying it.

It will not display the second question and inline keyboard for me to select the answer. I believe the state didn't pass to questionTwo, but I am not sure which part is wrong.

```
import logging
from telegram import (ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove,InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup)
from telegram.ext import (Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters,
                          ConversationHandler,CallbackQueryHandler)

answerOne, answerTwo = range(2)


def start(update, context):
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Option 1", callback_data='1'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Option 2", callback_data='2'),
        ],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Option 3", callback_data='3')],
    ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    update.message.reply_text('Please choose:', reply_markup=reply_markup)
    return answerOne

def button(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query

    # CallbackQueries need to be answered, even if no notification to the user is needed
    # Some clients may have trouble otherwise. See https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text(text="Selected option: {}".format(query.data))
    return questionTwo

def questionTwo(update, context):
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Option 4", callback_data='4'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Option 5", callback_data='5'),
        ],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Option 6", callback_data='6')],
    ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    update.message.reply_text('Please choose:', reply_markup=reply_markup)
    return answerTwo


def answerTwo(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query

    # CallbackQueries need to be answered, even if no notification to the user is needed
    # Some clients may have trouble otherwise. See https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text(text="Selected option: {}".format(query.data))


def cancel(update, context):
    user = update.message.from_user
    logger.info("User %s canceled the conversation.", user.first_name)
    update.message.reply_text('Bye! I hope we can talk again some day.',
                              reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())

    return ConversationHandler.END


def main():
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    # Make sure to set use_context=True to use the new context based callbacks
    # Post version 12 this will no longer be necessary
    updater = Updater('TOKEN', use_context=True)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],

        states={
            answerOne: [CallbackQueryHandler(button)],
            questionTwo:[MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, questionTwo)],
            answerTwo:[CallbackQueryHandler(answerTwo)],
        },

        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)]
    )

    dp.add_handler(conv_handler)
    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import logging
from telegram import (ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove,InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup)
from telegram.ext import (Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters,
                          ConversationHandler,CallbackQueryHandler)

answerOne, questionTwo = range(2)

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO
)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def start(update, context):
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Option 1", callback_data='1'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Option 2", callback_data='2'),
        ],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Option 3", callback_data='3')],
    ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    update.message.reply_text('Please choose:', reply_markup=reply_markup)
    return answerOne

def button(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query

    # CallbackQueries need to be answered, even if no notification to the user is needed
    # Some clients may have trouble otherwise. See https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text(text="Selected option: {}".format(query.data))
    return questionTwo

def questionTwo(update, context):
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Option 4", callback_data='4'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Option 5", callback_data='5'),
        ],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Option 6", callback_data='6')],
    ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    update.message.reply_text('Please choose:', reply_markup=reply_markup)
    return answerOne


def cancel(update, context):
    user = update.message.from_user
    logger.info("User %s canceled the conversation.", user.first_name)
    update.message.reply_text('Bye! I hope we can talk again some day.',
                              reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())

    return ConversationHandler.END


def main():
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    # Make sure to set use_context=True to use the new context based callbacks
    # Post version 12 this will no longer be necessary
    updater = Updater('Token', use_context=True)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],

        states={
            answerOne: [CallbackQueryHandler(button)],
            questionTwo:[MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, questionTwo)]
        },

        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)]
    )

    dp.add_handler(conv_handler)
    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what did you change and why did you change it? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64496203/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 2 years ago"*. Perhaps somebody else can chime in?